# Mistake in proof that affine linear group is unimodular

Tags: measure-theory, topological-groups, haar-measure

Where is the mistake in the following argument? I am arguing that the affine group on $\mathbb{R}^n$ is unimodular, which it is not!.

Let
$$\operatorname{Aff}_n(\mathbb{R}) := \left\{\begin{pmatrix} A & v\\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}: \, A \in \operatorname{GL}_n(\mathbb{R}), v \in \mathbb{R}^n\right\}$$
be the group of affine transformations on $\mathbb{R}^n$. Denote $h := \begin{pmatrix} A_h & v_h \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$.

Then I define $f: \operatorname{Aff}_n(\mathbb{R}) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$ via $h \mapsto \vert \det A_h \vert^{-(n+1)}$ and claim that the measure $\mu$ having density $f$ w.r.t. the $n+1$-dimensional Lebesgue measure $\lambda^{n+1}$ is **left and right** translation invariant.

Let $g \in \operatorname{Aff}_n(\mathbb{R})$ and $B$ a Borel set of $\operatorname{Aff}_n(\mathbb{R})$ be arbitrary. Then by definition

$$ \mu(gB) = \int_{gB} f(h) d\lambda^{n+1}(h)$$

Now note that $gB = g_l (B)$ where $g_l: G \rightarrow G$ via $g_l(h) = gh$. This function is smooth, so one can apply the Jacobi transformation formula to obtain

$$\int_{B} \vert \det D(g_l) \vert f(g_l(h)) d\lambda^{n+1}(h)$$

Now note that $D(g_l) = I_n \otimes g$ and $f(g_l(h)) = f(gh)$ which gives

$$\int_{B} \vert \det A_g \vert^{n+1} f(gh) d\lambda^{n+1}(h)$$

Now we use that

$$\vert \det A_{gh} \vert^{-(n+1)} = \vert \det A_h \vert^{-(n+1)} \vert \det A_g \vert^{-(n+1)}$$

to finally get

$$\int_{B} \vert \det A_h \vert^{-(n+1)} d\lambda^{n+1}(h) = \int_{B} f(h) d\lambda^{n+1}(h) = \mu(B)$$

Now we make the same argument for $Bg$ i.e. $g_r(B)$ where $g_r(h) = hg$. Then the only difference is that $D(g_r) = g^T \otimes I_n$, but the determinant of this matrix is also $\vert \det A_g \vert^{(n+1)}$. Also for the second term in the integrand we have

\begin{align}
f(g_r(h)) = f(hg) &= \vert \det A_{hg} \vert^{-(n+1)} \\
&= \vert \det (A_{h} A_g) \vert^{-(n+1)} \\
&= \vert \det A_{h} \det A_g \vert^{-(n+1)} \\
&= \vert \det A_{h} \vert^{-(n+1)} \vert \det A_g \vert^{-(n+1)} \\
\end{align}

which is the same as before. Hence also $\mu(Bg) = \mu(B)$ which means that the left and right Haar measure conicide.

So the question is: Where do I go wrong?

Any comments, suggestions or references are very much appreciated too.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: To converge to the error, you could stick to $g=(2I_n,0)$. Then you claim that $g_\ell$ and $g_r$ preserve the given measure but this is not the case, and more precisely $g_\ell g_r^{-1}$ does not preserve the given measure (if $n\ge 1$). The interest is that $g_\ell g_r^{-1}(A_h,v_h)=(A_h,2v_h)$, which is a particularly simple form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that you need to consider the $(n+1)^2$-dimensional Lebesgue measure here since you embed $\operatorname{Aff}_n(\mathbb{R})$ into $\mathbb{R}^{(n+1) \times (n+1)} \cong \mathbb{R}^{(n+1)^2}$.

Otherwise the calculations are correct, but the constructed left and right translation invariant measure $\mu$ is trivial because $\operatorname{Aff}_n(\mathbb{R})$ is a null set:$$\lambda^{(n+1)^2}(\operatorname{Aff}_n(\mathbb{R}) )\leq \lambda^{(n+1)^2}(\mathbb{R}^{n^2+n} \times \{0\}^n \times \{1\}) = 0.$$ Hence $\mu$ is not a Haar measure and your argument does not contradict the fact that $\operatorname{Aff}_n(\mathbb{R})$ is not unimodular.